# wp_enqueue_style url is trimmed somehow

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

I am using a plugin that adds a style with `wp_enqueue_style()`.

When I look at the page source I find this line:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='ai1ec_style-css'  href='http://heseg.com/' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

After looking at the plugin code I found the `wp_enqueue_style` method and printed the values that it sends and I find that the URL is:

```
http://heseg.com/?ai1ec_render_css=1376759122ai1ec_style
```

It looks like the URL is trimmed to `'http://heseg.com/'`

What can cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the ID attribute `id='ai1ec_style-css'` that stylesheet is for All-in-One Event Calendar plugin.

If you just updated the All_in-One Event Calendar (the most recent update was yesterday 2013-8-16) try re-saving the calendar theme options in **Events->Theme Options**.

This answer is based on this support topic. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/broken-links-inside-plugin-after-updating-to-196

Comment: I am in the latest version 1.11.2, thanks

Comment: You may want to look at other plugins you have installed. In particular any plugin that might alter the output of scripts in the header.

The script URL includes a `?` and it is possible that another plugin removes anything starting at the `?`.

Plugins that minify scripts or alter version numbers at the end of script URLs would be a possible cause.

Comment: thanks, that was it. There was a code in the functions.php that trimmed the string after the '?'.